# What seforim or books were written on the Torah approach to modern-day philosophy such as humanism or classical liberalism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, jewish-books, morality

Although I have seen paragraphs here and there in various books explaining the torah hashkafa on specific values (i.e. Rav Kook, Rav Illowy, Lord Sacks on slavery), I have yet to seen a book that holistically describes what the torah approach is to modern-day western values. For example, do we try at all to reconcile Torah with our modern day moral conscience, or are we supposed to derive all our values organically from the Torah and let the chips fall where they may.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: R' S.R. Hirsch's Nineteen Letters

Comment: So far the answers are Rav Hirsch and Postmodernism. Did any East European/charedi rabbonim write anything about this subject (perhaps someone like R Dessler?)

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch and his [teachings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah_im_Derech_Eretz) seems to have had what to say about this.

Also, check out [Rabbi Esriel Hildesheimer and the Creation of a Modern Jewish Orthodoxy](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=B7fRPeByuzsC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=rav%20hirsch%20on%20modern-day%20western%20values&source=bl&ots=3aFzbDeRc9&sig=ACfU3U0C1pz2sxa3UEA4o8aoTF_Lv2o1mA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnh7_gjrvqAhU3QkEAHTegAaoQ6AEwCnoECBAQAQ#v=onepage&q=rav%20hirsch%20on%20modern-day%20western%20values&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

If you can read Hebrew -  "Two wagons and a balloon - Judaism and post-modernism" By Rabbi Michael Avraham.

[image]

Comment: The question didn't ask about post-modernism....

Comment: @DoubleAA It did ask about modern day philosophy and humanism

Comment: Humanism isn't postmodernism

Comment: Modern day western values

Comment: @DoubleAA Is your sentence works the other way around as well?

Comment: postmodernism isn't humanism

Comment: 1. Postmodernism is not part of standard modern day western values.

Comment: 2. This book, judging from its cover, looks like just another attempt at making cute, pseudolomdish parallels between torah and xyz philosophy. If the author is truly attempting to show that the proper torah approach is, and always was, postmodernism, please let me know.

Comment: @JG I read just a small part of the book, since philosophy is not my thing. Also, It seems that this book relies on other works (non-Jewish), and still, the author is a Talmid-Chacham, and this book is pretty thick, so I wouldn't call it "cute" before reading it.